# Which tool should I use to record audio (or convert the recorded audio) in the format supported by Microsoft Speaker Recognition API?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out the Microsoft cognitive services, Speaker Recognition API in ASP.NET Core. However I've no idea how to give the audio file as the input of the following supported format:

Container-  WAV

Encoding-   PCM

Rate-   16K

Sample Format-  16 bit

Channels-   Mono

Can someone please help me out with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the input mode to be wav:

// Configure the input to the recognizer.

recognizer.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\temp\SampleWAVInput.wav");

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Recognition_SpeechRecognitionEngine_SetInputToWaveFile_System_String_) discusses how to recognize audio files with the recognizer in the System.Speech namespace.

you can also try with [SetInputToAudioStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtoaudiostream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Recognition_SpeechRecognitionEngine_SetInputToAudioStream_System_IO_Stream_System_Speech_AudioFormat_SpeechAudioFormatInfo_) with the format of the input.